# Add an object with Text on it on vertical surface (wall) - ARCore Android studio

Tags: android-studio, augmented-reality, arcore

I am developing an AR application with android studio and ARcore.

What I am trying to do is to **add objects with texts on them on a vertical surface**.

I found that I can add text on a ViewRenderable but as i understand the ViewRenderable is attached with another object so i don't that is what I need.

Could anyone help me I would appreciate it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can place an anchor on the vertical wall and then attach the ViewRenderable node to that (make it a child of the anchor node object).